# How to retrieve Shopify's 'extensions' object in GraphQL response for query cost data

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql, shopify

I have a React app that I have cloned from the [shopify-app-node repo](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node) (the latest version using Express). I'm making GraphQL calls to Shopify's Admin API and I would like to also return cost information. I understand that there is an extensions object that contains this information but it is not returned in a typical GraphQL call. I have attempted to read and understand the documentation of [Shopify/shopify-node-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shopify-api-node) but Shopify's current version of their React app doesn't reflect what the documentation states. Not in a way I can understand anyway.

This is the route defined when the server is initiated:

```
app.post("/graphql", verifyRequest(app), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const response = await Shopify.Utils.graphqlProxy(req, res);
      res.status(200).send(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  });
```

And then I make the query with the following: (apolloClient is being passed down from the parent component as this is a helper function and useQuery won't work due to it being a hook.

```
const apolloClient = useApolloClient();
    
apolloClient.query({
    query: GqlProducts,
    variables: {
        count: 10
    }
})
.then( response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.extensions);
})
.catch( error => console.log(error) )
```

Obviously I get an undefined on response.extensions.

Along with any hints or suggestions on how to get this working, I'm also curious to know why it's not returned in a typical response.

Comment: There's a couple confusing information in your question. Shopify/shopify-node-api links to a third party library ([repo](https://github.com/MONEI/Shopify-api-node)), not the official Shopify one. That should explain why the documentation seems off between the 2 projects. You also say that you can't use `useQuery` because it's in a hook, but that's objectively incorrect. If you're saying that because you want to trigger the query later on, use `useLazyQuery`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I completely missed that repo being a third party library. It explains other confusion I had. 

What I meant about `useQuery` is that its a hook and I am wanting to fetch data in other helper functions, which isn't possible unless the hook is within another hook or a parent component.

I have since re-read a [Shopify post](https://shopify.engineering/rate-limiting-graphql-apis-calculating-query-complexity) stating that you add the `X-GraphQL-Cost-Include-Fields: true` in the header of your request to return extensions. This leads me to figuring out how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Apollo client header dynamically is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495727/setting-apollo-client-header-dynamically-is-not-working)

Comment: Specifically, [overriding default options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/advanced-http-networking/#overriding-options) to pass custom headers to the context.

Comment: I actually got it working soon after my previous comment! Thanks for pulling that up, though. It turns out the extensions object is actually being returned in the response, but it's not coming through to the app from the server for some reason. I've made a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022828/express-server-not-passing-shopify-extensions-object-back-to-app-in-graphql-re) where I explain more.