# Express server not passing Shopify 'extensions' object back to App in GraphQL response

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, shopify

I have a Shopify/React app which is using Express. I'm able to successfully make GraphQL calls to the admin API and receive the data back as expected, however, I'm also wanting to retrieve the extensions object which contains information on the cost of the query.

This is the Express route where I'm also logging the response:

```
  app.post("/graphql", verifyRequest(app), async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const response = await Shopify.Utils.graphqlProxy(req, res);
      
      console.log('response.body:', response.body)

      res.status(200).send(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
  });
```

This is my query within the app:

```
  apolloClient.query({
    query: GqlProducts,
    variables: {
      count: 10
    }
  })
  .then( response => console.log('response:',response) )
  .catch( error => console.log(error) )
```

I can see both `data` and `extensions` objects when I log the response within the server. This is the response in the terminal window where the server is running:

```
response.body: {
  data: {
    products: {
      pageInfo: [Object],
      edges: [Array],
      __typename: 'ProductConnection'
    }
  },
  extensions: {
    cost: {
      requestedQueryCost: 192,
      actualQueryCost: 53,
      throttleStatus: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

However, the `extensions` object does not seem to be available within the app. This is the response in the browser console:

```
response: 
{data: {…}, loading: false, networkStatus: 7}
    data:
        products: {__typename: 'ProductConnection', pageInfo: {…}, edges: Array(10)}
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    loading: false
    networkStatus: 7
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Is there something that I am missing for this object to be available?

Comment: You need to set `X-GraphQL-Cost-Include-Fields: true` header to your request to get the the data along with other data

Comment: I was originally passing that with my query, and I verified that it was being sent by inspecting the headers of the request in devtools, but it made no difference to being able to access it in the app. Seeing `extensions` was being returned in the server console.log, I omitted it to keep the code minimal for this post. ...Or would it actually make a difference, and maybe I was doing something else wrong to get the object?

Comment: ^^ just to clarify, I was still getting the extensions object in the server console.log without passing X-GraphQL-Cost-Include-Fields: true. This is why I stopped passing it through.